# Mid 2015 retina MacBook Pro: Startup slow after SSD Upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, performance, startup

I've recently upgraded my Mid 2015 retina MacBook Pro's original 500 GB SSD to a 2 TB Samsung EVO 970 NVMe M.2 coupled with a recent model Sintech SSD adaptor. I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I followed the procedure outlined [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU6yatTvyyk).

Ever since upgrading the SSD, startup time has significantly slowed. It's now always exactly 58 seconds from chime to login screen. It used to be around 20 seconds previously.

Black Magic speed tests show good high performance. Only startup is a drag.

Is this normal? Why would it be this slow? How can I fix/improve it?

Comment: "running the command "sudo trimforce disable" fixed the slow boot issue for me, since my boot drive is an SSD"

Further posters say this won't work on NVMe drives. And that you need to use HFS+J instead of APFS as filesystem (I believe this can be achieved by reformatting and then using something like Carbon Copy Cloner to copy over your data).

source: https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/slow-boot-time-with-samsung-960-evo-nvme.232322/page-5

(not familiar with the issue, I just literally googled your question..)

Comment: Thanks. The information about APFS vs HFS+J on NVMe SSDs seems to be correct. After further searching on the site you linked to I found a reference to solving this issue by installing macOS 10.14 Mojave. I did this and it has actually improved load speed from 58 seconds to 33 seconds, which is great. I think it may be further improvable but have yet to find a definitive solution that doesn't involve potentially damaging the file system. Other users talk about 10 second load times albeit on a smaller capacity SSD.

Comment: In verbose mode I can see this point where the boot process hangs.

“FIPSPOST_USER [3722302532] fipspost_post: 197: all tests PASSED (213 ms)
com_seagte_IOPowSec00_10_5: GetVendorAndModel ID Info failed 
com_maxtor_IOPowSec00_10_5: GetVendorAndModel ID Info failed
Warning: kexts unavailable; proceeding w/o lock for <unknown>
Warning: couldn’t block sleep during cache update
Warning: proceeding w/o DiskArb
Warning: /AppleInternal/Library/Extensions: No such file or directory
/dev/disk1s1 on / (apfs, local, journaled)
0x91 0x2A 0x00 0xD0 00x3F 0x00 0x07 0x47"

Comment: I think you might get more responses in a hackintosh forum since this goes beyond the regular Mac scope

Comment: Any updates? Mine reaches only 2.5GB/s read instead of 3.5GB/s like advertised. And also sometimes it feels like it hangs on read/write